# How should I understand "des" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, sens, prépositions, articles

> La France est un **des** grands pays de l'Europe occidentale.

I learned this sentence from the book *French for Reading Knowledge*. The word "des" does not make sense for me. "un grands pays" (a great country) looks right to me. Is it an indefinite article or a partitive article? Or something else? What is the grammar here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Pays** is a word that has the same form in the singular and in the plural. It always has an **s** in the end.

In :

> un des grands pays

it is plural. And you can tell it is plural because the adjective **grands** has an **s**, since in French adjectives agree with the nouns they modify.

Here **des** (standing for **de les**) is a preposition followed by the plural definite article.

If you wanted to say *a great country* it would be **un grand pays** with no **s** a the end of “grand”.

“Un(e) des …” is another way of saying “un(e) parmi les …“ (One among the, one of the…)

Comment: As a parallel, you could consider the grammatically identical sentence "Napoléon était un des grands hommes de l'histoire française".  It's a bit more obvious in this case that "hommes" is plural.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You'd think « grands » is obvious enough

Comment: @PierreArlaud:  it definitely should be, but if a novice French speaker is coming from a first language without adjective agreement, they may not think to look for at the number and gender of the adjective for clues.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence

> La France est un des grands pays de l'Europe occientale

can be translated as

> France is one of the major countries of Western Europe

*un des* is here used to say *one of the*

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence "un des" is like "one of".

Here the meaning is:

> France is one of the greatest countries in Western Europe.

(My english is still bad, sorry, but the meaning of "des" is correctly translated)

Comment: No, the meaning is "one of the great countries of [...]". What you wrote would be "un des **plus** grands pays [...]" in French.